# Edit existing desktop shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcuts

I am attempting to edit a desktop shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04. I changed my copy of the shortcut in .local/share/applications to change the name of the shortcut. I then rebooted Ubuntu but the old copy of the shortcut with the old name was still displayed in the desktop dock. What do I have to do to get the new copy used? I have no problems creating a new shortcut, only in editing an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you have to rename the desktop file in `.local/share/applications` to change the name of the icon in the desktop toolbar where the displayed name is shown.